# How to use Proxy to intercept every function of an object in JavaScript or E6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy, es6-class, es6-proxy

I have a class A, defined like below.(All sample code is simplified for privacy)

```
 class A{
     Func1(){

    } 
    Func2(){

    }
    Func3(){

    }
 }
```

And I want to make every function in A running after another function Func4();
So I write a fuction to intercept through Proxy like below:

```
   _Intercept(object) {
        if (object === undefined || object === null) {
            throw new Error('intercept need non null object');
        }

        const objectPrototypes = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
        const objectPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objectPrototypes);
        for (const index in objectPropertyNames) {
            const protoName = objectPropertyNames[index];

            if (!object.__proto__.hasOwnProperty(protoName)) {

                continue;

            }

            let originalFunction = object.__proto__[protoName];
            if (originalFunction === undefined || originalFunction === null) {

                continue;
            }

            if (typeof (originalFunction) !== 'function') {

                continue;
            }
            if (protoName === 'constructor') {

                continue;
            }
            console.log(object.__proto__[protoName]);

            object.__proto__[protoName] = new Proxy(originalFunction, {

                apply(target, thisArg, argArray) {
                    console.log("you intercept this func");

                    return Reflect.apply(...arguments);
                }
            });
        }

        return object;
```

And in another main.js, I write code like this:

```
var a=new A();
a = _Intercept(a);
var b=new B();
b = _Intercept(b);
a.Func1();
```

But in chrome console, there output two lines "you intercept this func"
How could this happen? I've only apply a.Func1() clearly, why print two lines??

And when I try delete  "b = _Intercept(b)" in main.js or delete "  return Reflect.apply(...arguments);" in function _Intercept, it will only print one line.
Is anyone know about this situation ? Is my wrong use?Or ES6 Proxy bug?
Or Someone gimme some better dynamic proxy in javascript rather than Proxy in ES6??

I've tried another version before, use objectPrototypes  rather than **proto**, but it works no good.

```
 objectPrototypes[name] = new Proxy(originalFunction, handler);
```

Comment: You should use `objectPrototypes` instead of `object.__proto__`

Comment: Your problem is that `_Intercept(a)` modifies `A.prototype`, and `_Intercept(b)` modifies `A.prototype` again. If you want to intercept method calls on individual instances, you should not mess with the prototype. If you want to intercept method calls on all instances, you should call `_Intercept` on the class itself, and only once.

Comment: @Bergi  I've tried another version before, use   objectPrototypes[name] = new Proxy(). And it works no good, output two lines

Comment: The fact that you are using proxies to intercept the call has nothing to do with the problem.